# Can the syntax coloring script please learn that C++ AMP is C++?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

I'm reading a question in [c++-amp](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-amp) that includes a wall of code. To be honest, most questions in that tag include a wall of code. And it looks crummy:

[image]

I believe the highlighting is based on the tag. So can somebody add a line somewhere that uses C++ highlighting for questions in the C++ AMP tag?

ps: I edited that particular question (it was not written in clear English) and added a language hint to the code. That's why I provided a screenshot, because that question has proper highlighting now.

Comment: Well, if the question contains C++ code just add C++ tag..

Comment: All C++ AMP code contains C++ code. I don't think clutttering up the C++ tag with questions about nonstandard C++ (parallel_for_each is not in the STL and neither restrict(amp) nor tile_static are C++ 11) will help anyone.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd if adding tag like this would do about the same as adding [tag:java] tag would do to [tag:java-me] question (hint: no good) then your advice is pretty slippery

Comment: I once suggested not to use [tag:php] for Drupal questions, if the questions was about functions implemented by Drupal, and not from PHP. From the answer I got, I felt like being seen as an alien. I wonder why not using the language tag for some framework/library is understandable, but it is not for other frameworks/libraries.

Comment: @gnat you might be correct. I believe there is "mapping" that cause [tag:jquery] tag to act as [tag:javascript] as far as the prettify is concerned though I'm not sure how it's done i.e. if it's on "our" side or the native prettify code side.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I think sometimes language tags carry a bit of a "typically implied context" which could make a bad fit in specific cases. [tag:java] is a good example: though in theory it is platform / language version agnostic, but average reader associates it with Java SE 5+ - which not coincidentally makes a perfect sense almost always, except for [tag:java-me] where assuming this is a disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've turned on C++ syntax highlighting for this tag.